# Table in Oracle DB not visible after initialization with docker compose

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I'm not experienced with Docker and got stuck on one of my experiments with `docker compose`. I'm trying to spin up an Oracle database (image: gvenzl/oracle-xe).

I also add two SQL scripts to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory, one to create a user and another one to create a table. When I perform the `docker compose up` command, the logging shows that these scripts are picked up, and a user (of the first script) is indeed created. However, I cannot find my table anywhere when I connect to the running container with SQLDeveloper.

I have made a custom image where I use `ADD` to place these files into the correct directory (not shown here, but confirmed that they are there). Below are the files that I'm using:

**docker-compose.yml** (just added line numbers for easy reference if something is wrong)

```
  1 version: "3.8"     
  2            
  3 services:  
  4   db-oracle-xe:    
  5     build: .       
  6     restart: on-failure    
  7     image: oracle-xe:latest
  8     environment:   
  9       ORACLE_PASSWORD: some_pass
 10       APP_USER: someuser   
 11       APP_USER_PASSWORD: some_other_pass
 12     volumes:       
 13       - some-data:/var/docker-data/oracle
 14     ports: 
 15       - "1521:1521"
 16            
 17 volumes:   
 18   some-data:
```

**0-create-user.sql**

```
CREATE USER TEST;
```

**1-create-table.sql**

```
  1 create table TEST.SOME_TABLE
  2 (
  3     ID                                  NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
  4     ADDED_DATE                          VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),     
  5     NAME                                VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)      NOT NULL,
  6     CREATED_TIME                        TIMESTAMP               NOT NULL,
  7 );
```

I'm completely stuck and would appreciate some feedback or perhaps tips on what I should do to troubleshoot this issue. It might be really simple what I'm doing wrong, so hoping to learn form this

Comment: If the create table statement did not fail, then there is a table.  How are you determining that there is not?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I'm connecting to the database with SQLDeveloper to verify that there is a table with the name that I specified. But I can't see any table, which is the confusing part

Comment: are you connecting as the TEST user?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I tried a few flavors (connecting as 'test' and also as 'someuser') but in both cases I can't see anything. I also removed the TEST from TEST.SOME_TABLE during creation, but this did not result in anything different

Answer (score 3):

You need to connect with username and password before creating tables.

[check this blog for more details](https://fullstackcode.dev/2022/07/09/run-oracle-database-with-docker/) , it worked for me